# PDO - "Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know that error occurs usually when query returned false but this time this occurs with no reason! (or just I'm making a big mistake)

```
    if(!$security_SenderId){
        $getbaseticketqry = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tickets` WHERE `ticket_safeid` = '?'");
        $getbaseticket = $getbaseticketqry->execute(array($ticket_safeid));
    }else{
        $getbaseticketqry = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tickets` WHERE `ticket_safeid` = '?' AND `ticket_sender` = '?'");
        $getbaseticket = $getbaseticketqry->execute(array($ticket_safeid, $security_SenderId));
    }

    if($getbaseticket === false){
        return false;
    }else{
        $baseticket = $getbaseticket->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

I've theese lines in a function that returns support ticket information as array but as I said the error occurs when I tried to fetch the ticket information. I tried to check mysql errors just before fetch line by enabling the pdo debug mode and `db->errorInfo()` but it didn't work.

What can the problem be here?

Edit:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class TICKET_MANAGER
{
    function __construct($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass) {
        try{
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }

    function viewTicket($ticket_safeid, $security_SenderId = false)
    {
        try{
            if(!$security_SenderId){
                $getbaseticketqry = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tickets` WHERE `ticket_safeid` = ?");
                $getbaseticket = $getbaseticketqry->execute(array($ticket_safeid));
            }else{
                $getbaseticketqry = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tickets` WHERE `ticket_safeid` = ? AND `ticket_sender` = ?");
                $getbaseticket = $getbaseticketqry->execute(array($ticket_safeid, $security_SenderId));
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die('Mysql error: ' . $e->getMessage() );
        }
        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: How are you using the `TICKET_MANAGER` class?

Comment: I've seperated files for ticket management (viewticket.php, newticket.php etc.). I include that class file in viewticket.php and I create a new instance of TICKET_MANAGER then I just use viewTicket() function to get ticket information and replies. It gets the ticket_safeid from $_POST and senderId from session. I'm sure that safeid and senderId goes to function correctly.

Comment: *"and senderId from session"* - are you using sessions per se?

Comment: I get the logged in user's id as sender id to get his own tickets. What do you mean by se?

Comment: This is what I meant by if you're using sessions http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Plus, maybe your user login is failing and something else along the way. You'll need to go over your entire login code and how it's being passed over to the other pages. If you are indeed using PHP sessions, make sure that `session_start();` is inside all pages and that the session arrays are indeed set.

Comment: As I said before, the $ticket_safeid and $secure_SenderId gets to the function correctly. I also tried to writing that variables manually but it didn't work. The problem is about pdo or mysql.

Answer (score 2):

It's the quotes around all your `'?'` - Remove them.

Read the manual

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

from the manual:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
```

Exceptions should have told you that error

```
setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
```

and used right after you've connected to your DB.

---

-http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Query:

```
try {

// your query

}
    catch(PDOException $e){
     print  $e->getMessage();
    }
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Removing the single quotes didn't work. Also I've tried the setAttribute() thing right after the db connection as you said but it didn't throw any error too.

Comment: @ibrahimduran Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @ibrahimduran Plus, just to make sure. Your connection in fact PDO and not `mysqli_`, correct? Are you using a class also? Update your question with how you're using the exceptions under your original question as to not overwrite your original code.

Comment: I'm not using class for database connections, I've edited my post, check it out.

Comment: Also the other functions (newTicket etc.) work correctly. I'm having problem only with this function.

Comment: @ibrahimduran You also have many variables that I don't know where they're being used/assigned as, including how you're using the `TICKET_MANAGER` class. Check your column types also, or that data doesn't contain spaces; could be anything.